# Generic DAO search method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, genericdao

I have a scenario in which there are two entity classes. Their structures are like

```
Class A{
Long id;
// some fields
}

Class B{
Long id;
Long associtedA;
// some field
}
```

The field associtedA in entity B refers to A.id
The relation between them is A one-to-many B

I need to get the list of A and with them related B data list.

I tried to implement this using search. But I am not able to find some working solution. Also I cannot change the entity.

I can implement this by retrieving all the A list then for each A.id again retrieving related B data. But for that I have to make service call in loop, which is something I don't want.

Is there any smart way to this scenario?

Comment: That the field `associtedA` is of type `Long` but not of type `A` looks like a bug (misunderstood hibernate mapping concepts). Are you sure that you can not change the entities? (maybe you can change the classes but not the database?)

Comment: Its not a bug!!! Its completely right according to my structure.  In my database these two are not the only entities,there are other entities also. And they are dependent on each other. So for my situation this was the only way to make them.. I cant explain the whole structure here. But this mapping support my database structure. P S I have already mentioned in the question that I cant change the entity.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at JinQ (http://www.jinq.org)
Then you could do:

```
streamProvider.streamAll(entityManager, B.class).join((a, source) -> source.stream(A.class)
.where(pair -> pair.getOne().id == pair.getTwo().id)
.select(pair -> pair.getOne())
.toArray()
```

Think this is the smartest way ;) (Of course you would need Java 8 for Lambda Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, these entities seem to be wrong. Are you using JPA? An entity manager?

If you are using an entity manager (such as Hibernate for example) Class B would be something like this:

```
Class B{
  Long id;
  A associtedA;
  // some field
}
```

See that B.associtedA is of type A.